# Running pytest inside emacs results in ugly output

Tags: python, testing, emacs, pytest

If I run `pytest` inside of Emacs, using `M-X compile`, `$TERM` gets set to "dumb", and this seems to confuse pytest's attempt to draw a line of `=`s across the full width of the screen.  It gets the width one too high, resulting in hard to read output with extra folded lines.

Running `unset COLUMNS; pytest` helps a little, but it's still trying to do some fancy overwriting by issuing raw carriage-returns, and messing that up.  I've also tried setting various values for `$TERM` (`ansi`, `glass-tty`, etc).  I even tried, `unset TERM`.

Any way to convince pytest to just produce dumb output and not try to do any fancy output formatting?

I'm also open to ideas on how to pistol-whip emacs into setting the environment correctly :-)

I'm running:

- GNU Emacs 22.1.1
- Python 3.6.2
- pytest version 3.4.0
- MacOS 10.12.6 (16G1212)
- Terminal Version 2.7.3 (388.1.1)

Comment: *cough* stop using emacs *cough*.....did someone say something?

Comment: @idjaw: The same could be said about python... but neither is helpful.

Comment: @choroba Right. We're not allowed being funny here, I forgot. I think we can lighten up and have a joke here and there.

Comment: It looks like I can hack this with "unset COLUMNS; pytest | tr '\015' '\012'", but hoping for something cleaner.

Comment: @idjaw As an Emacs user, i don't find your comment funny.

Comment: @choroba. Getting offended over something like this is silly. Of course just use whatever <tech> you want. We're all mostly professionals here and really should have, to a degree a sense of humour. There's a long list of other things to get offended at before getting upset at this.

Comment: does emacs use a pseudotty to run the command?

Answer (score 0):

Try [pytest.el](https://github.com/ionrock/pytest-el), or at least check how it invokes `py.test`. I use it with Spacemacs (it's included in the [Python layer](https://www.spacemacs.org/layers/+lang/python/README.html)), and have never seen any issues with its terminal handling.